# If $0<x,0<\alpha$, then $0<x^\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, exponential-function

If $0<x,0<\alpha$, then $0<x^\alpha$ 
I know that If $x<y$ and $a>1$, then $a^x<a^y$
And I know the exponential laws.
How can I prove it without differentation?

Comment: Not suitable for this site.

Comment: $x^\alpha=e^{\alpha \ln x}>0$.

Comment: @superdumb How exactly is $x^\alpha$ defined for irrational $\alpha$ in this context?